# zk button using Watir generates error indicating no button is present

Tags: watir, zk

I´m testing a zk form, and I want to click a button. My zk code is the following:

```
<zk:button id="btnLogin"
label="Entrar" onClick="wndLogin.onLogin()"
style="font-weight: bold; font-size:12px;" />
```

My watir code is shown below:

```
browser.button.click
```

I only have one button on the page. When I run the script, I get an error that indicates that a button does not exist on the page.

Comment: Do you know of any public page that has an example `zk:button`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is caused by the namespace - ie 'zk'. I have only been successfully with elements or attributes in a namespace by using css selectors:

```
browser.element(:css => 'zk\:button').click
```

Note that the colon needs to be escaped.

Comment: I still having an error: `D:/local/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:490:in assert_exists: unable to locate element, using {:css=>"zk\\:button"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownO
bjectException)`

Comment: I solved it: `browser.element(:class => 'z-button-tl').click`